# Three.js async texture load problems

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, three.js

I'm creating geometries inside a callback function of a texture Loader:

```
new RGBELoader().load('textures/image.hdr', function(hdrmap) {

        //Process Texture
        let envmap = envmaploader.fromCubemap(hdrmap);
        let texture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(new FlakesTexture());
        
        const physical_material = {
            color: 0xAFAFAF,
            normalMap: texture,
            normalScale: new THREE.Vector2(0.15,0.15),
            envMap: envmap.texture
        };
       
       const ring = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.TorusGeometry(20, 1, 64, 256), 
                    new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial(physical_material));
       scene.add(ring);
 });
```

Problem:

```
function animate() {
        const frame = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        TWEEN.update();

        //Problem:
        ring.rotation.x += 0.005;
        ring.rotation.y += 0.005;

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
```

The animation() function is defined outside the callback function and uses "ring" which on the runtime is not available...

How do I solve that? Do I need to put everything inside the .load calback function and if so: What about the functions???

Thanks for any help guys :).

Answer (score 0):

...my fault.

I simply added

```
let ring;
```

before calling the loader.
Inside the loader I just initialised "ring" with a new geometry / mesh:

```
ring = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.TorusGeometry(20, 1, 64, 256), new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial(physical_material));
```

Sorry :)